# Silence and vibration scheduler

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, automation, vibration, silent-mode

I used to have `Silet Time` on **Android 4.4** and it worked really well.

The application sets silent mode or vibration at scheduled time of the week.

I now have **Android 6** and that application does not work anymore; I also tried `Silent Hours` and several others.

The `Do not disturb` mode works but it doesn't allow setting vibration, only full silent mode which is good for sleeping, but not in other occasions (office hours, meetings, etc).

Is there a way to achieve this on **Android 6**?

Comment: What happens if you  turn the volume all the way down to get to vibrate or tap the button up or down then touch the "Sound" icon then choose vibrate?

Comment: @beeshyams I doubt that is a duplicate. The linked question is about setting the mode manually via volume keys. Here, OP asks about setting it automatically ("at scheduled time of the week"). Might be a candidate for the [tag:automation] tag to make it clearer. The goal can probably reached via [tag:tasker] and the *SecureSettings* addon, but I'm not sure (didn't try for the specific mode requested here).

Comment: @Izzy will add the automation tag, isn't tasker a paid app? I would prefer a free one as I don't need the complexity of tasker only to put on vibrate at certain time.

Comment: Yes, Tasker is a paid app. A free 7-day trial is available, though (see our [tasker tag-wiki](/tags/tasker/info)). It's the app I'm using, hence I named it. For alternatives, be welcome to check with [my list of automation apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, suggest using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn.

- Your macro for scheduled priority  mode would look like this

Trigger (when to act ) is 5 days of week at the time and day required - here it is week days. Long press to add constraints, i.e,, schedule

[image]

- Also, you may need to switch to this mode *on demand*. You can use this macro for that. 
  Create this macro and save. Go to widgets of your home screen and drag and drop Macrodroid widget on any screen. Assign this macro to that widget and use it on demand

[image]

**Edit:** Missed (sorry) adding that you would require a second macro in the on demand case where action would be *Alarms Only* or other options as you wish to get out of priority mode ,say as in the case of meeting at office

Comment: Advantages of using over Tasker -1. It's free 2. You don't need to secure settings ( which incidentally hasn't been updated in a long while ) 3. Easy to implement - hardly any learning

Comment: Did you get to try this ?